# Internal energy from a canonical partition function

Tags: partition-function

How to derive this relation, though it looks simple in eyes $$U=-\frac{\partial ln Q}{\partial \beta}$$ where Q is a canonical partition function and $\beta=\frac{1}{K_BT}$

Comment: Are you referring the the canonical partition function or the grand canonical partition function? Typically the canonical partition function is represented by $Z$ and the grand canonical partition function is represented by $Q$. In that case $U=-\frac{1}{Z}\frac{\partial Z}{\partial \beta}$, which is different from what you are trying to show. The Wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_%28statistical_mechanics%29#Calculating_the_thermodynamic_total_energy) has a proof for the same.

Comment: I follow Huang mostly, so Q is for canonical partition function

Comment: That is fine but your question mentions that "Q is a partition function" which makes it a bit ambiguous. If you were to edit it to "Q is the canonical partition function" then it'd be clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to derive this relation, though it looks simple in eyes
>   $$U=-\frac{\partial Q}{\partial \beta}$$ where Q is a canonical
>   partition function and $\beta=\frac{1}{K_BT}$

I  think that you mean that 
Q is the *log* of the partition function, not the partition function.

If "Q" is really just the canonical partition function then (with Boltzmann's "k"=0)
$$
Q=\sum_n e^{-E_n/T}=\sum_n e^{-\beta E_n}\;,
$$
such that
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\beta}Q=\sum_n -E_n e^{-\beta E_n}\;,
$$
which is *not* $U$. Because you need another factor of the partition function in the denominator. So, if you consider
$$
\tilde Q\equiv \log\left(\sum_n e^{-\beta E_n}\right)\;,
$$
then 
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}\tilde Q}{\mathrm{d}\beta}=-U\;,
$$
and the proof of  this should be obvious from the expressions given above. And... well... I guess this is starting to feel almost like a homework problem, so probably I shouldn't go into too much detail.